# Display Graph into my webpage which is exported from Microsoft powerBI

Tags: json, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have I created graph using Microsoft powerBI and save it as .pbix file. Now I want to display that Graph into my website. So I tried to export into JSON but I not get any option to export that Graph into JSON formate. I tried to export embeded code also but Its also not working. So can anyone help me or Guide me how can I include that graph into my webpage. I am using free version of Microsoft powerBI.

I tried to search on Google but not find any solution

Answer (score 1):

**In Power BI Desktop:**

1. After creating your report, save the report.
2. In `Home -> Publish`. Click on publish to publish the report into Power BI Service. Refer [Publish Datasets and Report documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-upload-desktop-files).

**In Power BI Service:**

1. Once the report is published into [PBI service](https://app.powerbi.com/), go to the workspace where the report is published.
2. Open the report, Click on `File -> Embed report -> Publish to web (public)`.
3. Need to create a Embed code to embed a report in a public website. Refer to [Publish to web from Power BI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web).
4. Once embed code is created, you will get a iframe, which you can paste in your application.
5. And finally your Power BI report gets embedded in your application.